# How to find an isometry that maps the cartesian equation of ellipse to the cartesian equation of the canonical form of ellipse

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, conic-sections

In the euclidean space $E 2$
consider the ellipse $C$ with foci $F_1 = (1, 7)$ and $F_2 = (7, 7)$,

passing through the point $(4, 3)$.
(i) Find a cartesian equation of $C$.
(ii) Find a cartesian equation of the canonical form $C'$
of $C$.

(iii) Find an isometry which maps $C$ to $C$
'
.

### Solution

#### (i)

$16x^2-128x+25y^2-350y+1081=0$

#### (ii)

$\frac{(x-4)^2}{25} +\frac{(y-7)^2}{16}=1$

#### (iii)

This part of question is a little bit ambiguous,but I assume that I am asked to find the matrix representing isometry with respect to the canonical basis.

#### .

If i take two points on ellipse $(4,11)$ and $(9,7)$ i would have $(4,11) \rightarrow (4,11)$ and $(9,7)\rightarrow(9,7)$.Then, $11\times (9,7)-7\times(4,11)\rightarrow 11\times(9,7)-7\times(4,11)$ or $(71,0)\rightarrow(71,0)$ which means $(1,0)\rightarrow(1,0)$.For the other vector of canonical basis i have $(0,1)\rightarrow(0,1)$.Would i get the correct result for (iii) if a transposed two vectors and wrote it as matrix?

Comment: You just rewrite (i) to get your answer for (ii). Could I be right in that the canonical form is $(\frac{x}{5})^2+(\frac{y}{4})^2-1$ and for (iii) the answer should just be translating the centre?

Comment: As much as i understood, (i) cartesian equation of ellipse is (x-4)^2/25 + (y-7)^2/16=1 and canonical form (ii) is x^2/5+y^2/16=1 and what i need to find is the isometry that translates the center of an ellipse from (4,7) to (0,0)?

Comment: Apart from your typo, that's my understanding too.

Answer (score 1):

There’s nothing ambiguous about the question, although there is more than one possible answer to it.

Construct the isometry in two stages. First, find the translation that takes the center of the ellipse to the origin. Then, find a rotation or reflection that aligns the major axis of the ellipse with the $x$-axis. In this case, the original axis is already parallel to the $x$-axis, so the simplest thing to do is nothing—a pure translation works.

Note, though, that since any isometry that solves this problem involves a translation, it can’t be represented as a matrix unless you use homogeneous coordinates, for which you’d have a $3\times3$ matrix. You always decompose an affine transformation into the composition of a linear transformation and a translation, though, and then represent the linear part by a $2\times2$ matrix, which for the above isometry is just the identity.